# Using AJAX to determine success of no captcha recaptcha

Tags: javascript, ajax, recaptcha

Trying to implement the new no captcha recaptcha into my site with an AJAX call. If I use a basic form with a submit button, it works fine, but when I try implementing it via AJAX it fails.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/REST/takeFountainItem",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "g-recaptcha-response": $("#g-recaptcha-response").val()
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Is there a function I need to invoke or something ? If I look at the header information, it is sending a big long key, but no matter what the key fails to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a function to verify the captcha. You need to verify it prior to allowing your form to submit. Please see their documentation for further details: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

My setup is something like this:
    `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit'></script>`

```
var RC2KEY = 'sitekey';
function reCaptchaVerify(response) {
    if (response === document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value) {
        /* do something */
    }
}

function reCaptchaExpired () {
    /* do something when it expires */
}

function reCaptchaCallback () {
    grecaptcha.render('id', {
        'sitekey': RC2KEY,
        'callback': reCaptchaVerify,
        'expired-callback': reCaptchaExpired
    });
}
```